# TinyMCE in position fixed or set height container, floatpanels (e.g. dropdown menus) when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tinymce

TinyMCE floatpanels (`mce-floatpanel`) and tooltips (`mce-tooltip`) are set as children of `<body>` with `position: absolute`. I understand the necessity with regard to `z-index` etc, but it also creates a problem with scrolling in certain circumstances.

If TinyMCE is the child of a container which scrolls, the menus and tooltips become unmoored. For example:

- A `<div>` with `height: #px` and `overflow: auto` → [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jatezo/2/edit?html,css,output)
- A `<div>` with `position: fixed` → [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/varaqo/2/edit?html,css,output)

I've seen the following two solutions suggested:

- To specify the editor float elements' container, as in these TinyMCE issues:

  - [Dropdown panel is not properly affixed](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/2852)
  - [How to change floatPanel's parent?](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3496)
- To close or hide the menu by manipulating the DOM `onscroll` or `onmouseleave` etc, as in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36648655/1307154)

Specifying the editor container is seemingly not yet available.

The trouble with the second suggestion is twofold. First, it feels hacky and has hard to account for edge cases. Second, I'm using react.

The React component doing the scrolling is far up the hierarchy, with hundreds of descendants. Monitoring scroll from there with the [`onScroll SyntheticEvent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#ui-events) works, but scroll event fires extremely rapidly, including during initialization as data loads into sub-components altering their size.

I don't know where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

It turns out specifying the UI container is somewhat available, as an undocumented feature, as requested in [this bug](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/pull/2653) and implemented in [this commit](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/commit/7fd61eeac61e9a88dfe8ed3c4c0398b5ee0328e2). This is not the solution I hoped it would be, having various unexpected side effects and bugs.

At this point I'm considering bypassing React entirely and monitoring the DOM directly for scroll events from the TinyMCE wrapper.